# The sentence, containing going to + infinitive construction, without context

Tags: sentence-meaning, future-tense

Consider the following sentence **without context**:

> You are going to wash my socks.

I think that this sentence has the sense as `command to wash speaker's socks`.

But can it be interpreted in another meaning? That is, intention of wash speaker's socks.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. Although it is possible to interpret it as "You are on the way to wash speaker's socks", as in, you are about to wash them.  This is a case of how the sentence is said, rather than what is said, I'd say.

Comment: I'd like to suggest avoiding anything *out of context*. It's not very productive for learning, in my opinion.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I just want to consider all possible meanings of that sentence.

Comment: Why do you want to consider it without context? It has **no** meaning without context.

Comment: @StoneyB I thought, that such consideration will give more entirely understanding of `to going + infinitive` construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when the sentence is ended with a period, it would be interpreted as a command to wash the speaker's socks.

However, if spoken in a different intonation (ended with a question mark):

> You are going to wash my socks?

It would be interpreted as an expression of surprise on the speaker's part that the person they're talking to is going to wash their socks.

There are probably other variations in intonation that might lead to different implications. A lot in English depends on how something is said. But if I were to read your original sentence in absence of other context or vocal cues, yes, that's what I'd assume.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a prediction of future events. If the context is a fictional story of a time traveller it may be the time traveller simply staying what he knows will happen.

There is very little in English that is unambiguous without at least a little context.